# If h is a holomorphic non-vanishing function in the complex plane then h is the exponential of another function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show if $h(z)$ is a holomorphic function such  $\forall$$z\in$$\mathbb{C}$  $h(z)\neq0$ then $\exists$ $H(z)$ such $h(z)=e^{iH(z)}$.

I think I should define the Taylor series of $h(z)$ and then rearrange it so it looks like the Taylor series of an exponential function but I'm not sure if that will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $h$ has no zeros, the function $h'(z)/h(z)$ is holomorphic on the whole plane, so there exists $g$ such that $g'(z)=h'(z)/h(z)$. Since $g$ is determined up to a constant, we can make it so that $\exp(g(0))=h(0)$.

Now compute the derivative of $f(z)=h(z)\exp(-g(z))$ and conclude.

(Source: Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.)

Comment: It should be $\exp(g(0))=h(0)$.