# Either $f$ is a polynomial or $|f(z_j)| > e^{n|z_j|}. $

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Me and a friend of mine didn't manage to solve the following problem.

> Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be an intere holomorphic function having a finite number of zeroes. Then either $f$ is a polynomial or there is a succession $\{z_j\}$ such that $z_j \to \infty$ and there exist $r$ such that eventually $$|f(z_j)| > e^{r|z_j|}. $$

*Attempts*

Let's call $h = \frac{f}{g}$, where $g$ is the polynomial that vanishes on zeroes of $f$ with the same multiplicity of $f$.

- We tried to look at $\frac{h'}{h}$, the logarithmic derivative of $h$ , but without good ideas.
- One can observe that $h$, when it's not constant, must have an essential singularity at infty.

Comment: First step is good. Then consider that $\log h$ is a nonconstant entire function, hence grows at infinity at least linearly.

Comment: Could you please expand this to an answer? We honesty did not manage to.

Comment: Elaborating Michelle's point, notice that any entire function is either polynomial or grows super-polynomially. (In other words, any entire function that grows at most polynomially is indeed a polynomial.) This should be enough for your claim.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not a polynomial, then $h$ is a nonconstant entire function without zeros. Therefore, $\phi = \log h$ is a nonconstant entire function. So its derivative at some point $z_0$ is nonzero. By the Cauchy integral formula, 
$$
\phi'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z-z_0|=r} \frac{\phi(z)}{z^2}\,dz
$$
which implies that $\max_{|z-z_0|=r}|\phi(z)| \ge r|\phi'(0)|$. Translated back in terms of $h$, this yields
$$
\max_{|z-z_0|=r}|h(z)| \ge e^{r|\phi'(0)|}
$$

Comment: Why does $log(h)$ is entire?!

Comment: See [If h is a holomorphic non-vanishing function in the complex plane then h is the exponential of another function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1183905)